# How to get user data from Javascript user back to Django

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm using Django and Bootstrap to create a simple website.

In my `.html` file, I'm using Bootstrap to display a datepicker.

```
 <div id="datepicker"  ></div>
```

Also in the `.html`, I have some quick and dirty javascript code that gets updated when my datepicker gets clicked on.

```
    <script>
        function setup(){

            <SOME OTHER JS>

            $('#datepicker').on("changeDate", function() {
                $('#my_hidden_input').val(
                    $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
                );
            });
        $(document).ready(setup);
    </script>
```

I want to pass back this new date to my Django page. Basically I want to refresh the page with data pertaining to this new date, and my Django code knows how to handle the new date.

How should I do that? Should I redirect back to my current page, but add something to the URL so that Django's regex will pick it up? Or should I make it an Http GET with the new date?

Comment: Pass this in an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get data from server **without page refresh**:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'web/path/to/php/file.php',
    data: {
        post_date: $('#datepicker').val() //this is the data to post to server
    },
    success: function(res) {
        //code executed after server response. res - server response
        $('#datepicker').append(res); //modifying your html
    }
});
```

And in file.php for example:

```
echo $_POST['post_date']; //accessing your date on server side and return it
```

If you **do need to refresh** the page, you can send your data in url:

```
$('#datepicker').on("changeDate", function() {
   var val = $('#my_hidden_input').val(
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
   );
   val = encodeURIComponent(val); //encode data for url passing
   window.location.href = '?date = ' + val; //goto url with appended parameter
});
```

To get data you use:

```
$date = urldecode($_GET['date']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would this refresh my page with the new date? And why are we doing "POST"? I thought "POST" is only used when we want to update backend. In this case, I just want to refresh the page with the new date. No backend update required. thanks

Comment: @user3240688 Page won't be refreshed, your html will be appended by code in `success` block. POST is used when you need something to post to server and get response

Comment: i should have been more clear in my original question. I do want the page to get refreshed. I can write my Django code so that it serves the relevant data given the new date. I just need to know where the new date will be given to me. So do we still want the ajax command? @Sam

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function pass_this_to_backend(date){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: "/get_date/",
      data: { 'date':date },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) { alert(response); },
      error: function( rrror) { alert(error); }
    });

    }


    function setup(){

        <SOME OTHER JS>

        $('#datepicker').on("changeDate", function() {
            $('#my_hidden_input').val(
                $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
            );
             pass_this_to_backend(date);
        });
    $(document).ready(setup);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would this refresh my page with the new date? And why are we doing "POST"? I thought "POST" is only used when we want to update backend. In this case, I just want to refresh the page with the new date. No backend update require.